# How to read password protected PDF file in Nodejs and get it in buffer?

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf.js

**I tried using pdfjs-dist.
getting large json response.**

```
var PDFJS=require('pdfjs-dist');
PDFJS.getDocument({ url: 'p1.pdf', password: '' }).then(function(pdf_doc) 
{
console.log(pdf_doc);
}).catch(function(error) {
// incorrect password

// error is an object having 3 properties : name, message & code
});
```

**Response**
This is the whole response I am getting.
but I need response in buffer.
Can it be converted to buffer.

```
    PDFDocumentProxy {
    loadingTask:
    { _capability:
     { resolve: [Function], reject: [Function], promise: [Promise] },
 _transport:
  WorkerTransport {
    messageHandler: [Object],
    loadingTask: [Circular],
    commonObjs: [Object],
    fontLoader: [GenericFontLoader],
    _params: [Object],
    CMapReaderFactory: [DOMCMapReaderFactory],
    destroyed: false,
    destroyCapability: null,
    _passwordCapability: null,
    _networkStream: [PDFNodeStream],
    _fullReader: [PDFNodeStreamFsFullReader],
    _lastProgress: [Object],
    pageCache: [],
    pagePromises: [],
    downloadInfoCapability: [Object],
    numPages: 4,
    pdfDocument: [Circular] },
 _worker:
  { name: null,
    destroyed: false,
    postMessageTransfers: true,
    verbosity: 1,
    _readyCapability: [Object],
    _port: [LoopbackPort],
    _webWorker: null,
    _messageHandler: [Object] },
 docId: 'd0',
 destroyed: false,
 onPassword: null,
 onProgress: null,
 onUnsupportedFeature: null },
 _pdfInfo:
 { numPages: 4,
 fingerprint: '3432353738363537336c6e665361446f6f744f4a70' },
_transport:
  WorkerTransport {
 messageHandler:
  { sourceName: 'd0',
    targetName: 'd0_worker',
    comObj: [LoopbackPort],
    callbackId: 1,
    streamId: 1,
    postMessageTransfers: true,
    streamSinks: [Object],
    streamControllers: [Object: null prototype] {},
    callbacksCapabilities: [Object: null prototype] {},
    actionHandler: [Object],
    _onComObjOnMessage: [Function] },
 loadingTask:
  { _capability: [Object],
    _transport: [Circular],
    _worker: [Object],
    docId: 'd0',
    destroyed: false,
    onPassword: null,
    onProgress: null,
    onUnsupportedFeature: null },
 commonObjs: { objs: [Object: null prototype] {} },
 fontLoader:
  GenericFontLoader {
    docId: 'd0',
    nativeFontFaces: [],
    styleElement: null,
    loadingContext: [Object],
    loadTestFontId: 0 },
 _params:
  [Object: null prototype] {
    url: 'p1.pdf',
    password: '',
    rangeChunkSize: 65536,
    CMapReaderFactory: [Function: DOMCMapReaderFactory],
    ignoreErrors: true,
    pdfBug: false,
    nativeImageDecoderSupport: 'none',
    maxImageSize: -1,
    isEvalSupported: true,
    disableFontFace: true,
    disableRange: false,
    disableStream: false,
    disableAutoFetch: false,
    disableCreateObjectURL: false },
 CMapReaderFactory: DOMCMapReaderFactory { baseUrl: null, isCompressed: false },
 destroyed: false,
 destroyCapability: null,
 _passwordCapability: null,
 _networkStream:
  PDFNodeStream {
    source: [Object],
    url: [Url],
    isHttp: false,
    isFsUrl: true,
    httpHeaders: {},
    _fullRequest: [PDFNodeStreamFsFullReader],
    _rangeRequestReaders: [Array] },
 _fullReader:
  PDFNodeStreamFsFullReader {
    _url: [Url],
    _done: false,
    _storedError: null,
    onProgress: [Function],
    _contentLength: 112979,
    _loaded: 112979,
    _filename: null,
    _disableRange: false,
    _rangeChunkSize: 65536,
    _isStreamingSupported: true,
    _isRangeSupported: true,
    _readableStream: [ReadStream],
    _readCapability: [Object],
    _headersCapability: [Object] },
 _lastProgress: { loaded: 112979, total: 112979 },
 pageCache: [],
 pagePromises: [],
 downloadInfoCapability:
  { resolve: [Function], reject: [Function], promise: [Promise] },
 numPages: 4,
 pdfDocument: [Circular] } }
                                                                                                                                                                                        *ignore below text*
```

efwrg rgsretg resgerstgh;ergh ;resjgysregh regjes powrjgu oiuueryoeq uieqroeqreqrilih ehr oiyeroeq ioiyeqroeq oieyqrioeq oieqyr oiyeqr oiyeqrp ioqyet oiehr oiyerh oieyreq oiyheqri iohereqk ioheqr qerioyqereq ioehqriheq rioqehriqeb ioeqrhpeq ioeqrhiqe ioqehriq ioqerhioq oirhqeipor oiqehrieq ioehqrq ioeqhrieq iohqerpq ieqhrpeq ioeqhrpeq iheqrpqe oiehrpqe ieqhrqierh ioeqhr ieqhr ioeqrh piqerh ieqhr iheqr piheqr ioheqr iheqr ioeqhrp ioqhre oieqhr oeqiyr qoeiryf pouqer poqure pouqr pouqre[q poquerq poqeur[q poqeur poqwuer poquer[ poqwur[wq poqr[ poqwhr powrq pow

Comment: So are you able to read the pdf file now?

Comment: getting large response in json

Comment: unable to handle the response

Comment: What's your end goal? Do you need to get the text from the pdf page by page?

Comment: Yes I want it in text

Comment: i have added the response in the question

Comment: using pdfreader for parsing the pdf to text, but how to parse password protected pdfs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may open and read a password protected PDF like below. Working with your existing code:

```
var PDFJS = require('pdfjs-dist');
PDFJS.getDocument({ url: 'p1.pdf', password: '' }).then(function(pdf) 
{
  let text = [];
  for(let i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {
    pdf.getPage(i).then(function(page) {
      page.getTextContent().then(function(data) {
        for(let j = 0; j < data.items.length; j++) {
          text.push(data.items[j].str);
        }        
      });
    });
  }

}).catch(function(error) {
// incorrect password

// error is an object having 3 properties : name, message & code
});
```

Comment: getting error (node:11684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid page request

Comment: pdfreader is able to convert  non-password protected pdfs  to text. I cannot find any options for password there. do you have any idea ?

Comment: I have got the Point. Thnak you so much.

Comment: What changes did you make? Maybe I can add it to the answer.

Comment: var pdfjs=require("pdfjs-dist");
var fs=require('fs');
pdfjs.getDocument('p2.pdf').then((pdf)=>{
var strr="";
var cc=0;
var no=pdf.numPages;
function dodo(){
 fs.writeFileSync("p2.txt",strr);
}

for(let i=1;i<=pdf.numPages;i++)
{
 new Promise(done=>{
pdf.getPage(i).then((page) =>{

  page.getTextContent().then((textContent)=>{

     for(let j=0;j<textContent.items.length;j++)
     {
      strr+=textContent.items[j].str + '\r\n';

     }
  
done();
  })
 
});

}).then(()=>{
 cc++;
 if(cc==no)
 dodo();
}) 
}

})

Comment: number of pages starts from 1 not 0